# Incoherent behavior on Arduino/SD card

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, lcd

For my project, I use an µSD card, with the socket included in [this LCD screen](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/GTFT) for logging. A few months ago, it worked fine, I developped that side of the project, but now it just always answer "failed init of SD card".

I tried using the SDfat Library to troubleshoot, and i got a weird result :

This is the output i get from Quickstart :

```
Card succesfully initialized.

Card size: 2008 MB (MB = 1,000,000 bytes)

Volume is FAT16, Cluster size (bytes): 32768

Files found (date time size name) :

Success! Type any character to restart.
```

This is the output I get from SdInfo :

```
cardBegin failed
SD errorCode: 0x1
SD errorData: 0xFF
```

I tried formatting by SDFormatter, changing the µSD card (I tried 3 Transcend 2GB, i don't have any other to try on at the moment), and trying the wiring only with the sd part connected (cs, miso, mosi, sck, gnd, vcc) but nothing changed.
I also verified that removing the µSD card effectively changes the error to something along the "no card present or wiring problem" thingy.

Any idea on what could make that weird combination happen ?